# the map of the model always returns an empty object

Tags: java, jsp

Good evening, I have a Spring MVC project on an e-commerce site.
concerning cart management, when I add a product to the cart by clicking the "Ajouter au panier", it adds good, but the problem if I add another product, I show that the second product .
I made "println" and I noticed that "model.asMap (). get (" panier ")" always returns null. what is the problem please?
Here are some screen prints on the console, controller and index.jsp

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajouterAuPanier")
    public String ajouterAuPanier(@RequestParam Long idArticle, @RequestParam int quantite, Model model) {
        System.out.println("111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111");
        Panier panier = null;

        if (model.asMap().get("panier") == null) {
            System.out.println("222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222");
            panier = new Panier();
            System.out.println("333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333");
            model.addAttribute("panier", panier);
            System.out.println("9999999999999999999999999999999" + panier.getItems().size());
        } else System.out.println("555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555");

        panier = (Panier) model.asMap().get("panier");
        panier.addArticle(metier.getArticle(idArticle), quantite);
        model.addAttribute("categories", metier.listCategories());
        model.addAttribute("articles", metier.listArticles());
        return "index";
    }
```

Comment: It seems you forgot to add the printscreens. Could you add these please?

Comment: sorry i have a problem when i add printscreens!! can you give me your email to send you details !?

Comment: There are online services that can host the images for you such as imgur.com (no advertising intended)

Comment: Please update your question with `Panier`. Did you implement `equals()` / `hashCode()`?